# How to use words with accents and symbols in a xmacroplay Script line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I am using an xmacrorec/xmacroplay (from the package [xmacro](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/utils/xmacro)) in order to ***Record / Play keystrokes and mouse movements in X displays***.

I run:

```
xmacrorec > file.macro
```

Which results in a file named "file.macro" with the corresponding code which will be interpreted by xmacroplay in order to repeat every mouse move and/or keystrokes, a sample of the code is shown right here:

```
MotionNotify 6 97
KeyStrPress Super_L
KeyStrPress Return
KeyStrRelease Return
KeyStrRelease Super_L
KeyStrPress Alt_L
KeyStrPress d
KeyStrRelease Alt_L
KeyStrRelease d
KeyStrPress Control_L
KeyStrPress v
KeyStrRelease v
KeyStrRelease Control_L
KeyStrPress Return
KeyStrRelease Return
ButtonPress 1
ButtonRelease 1
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Shift_R
KeyStrPress b
KeyStrRelease Shift_R
KeyStrRelease b
KeyStrPress l
KeyStrRelease l
KeyStrPress a
KeyStrRelease a
KeyStrPress b
KeyStrRelease b
KeyStrPress l
KeyStrRelease l
KeyStrPress a
KeyStrRelease a
KeyStrPress b
KeyStrRelease b
KeyStrPress l
KeyStrRelease l
KeyStrPress a
KeyStrRelease a
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Tab
KeyStrRelease Tab
KeyStrPress Return
KeyStrRelease Return
```

As you can see and perhaps already knew, I can use the next code in order to reproduce keystrokes:

```
KeyStrPress a
KeyStrRelease a
```

Which will result in an "a".

So let's say I would like to write an "á" (an a with accent). I will need a portion of code like this:

```
KeyStrPress dead_acute
KeyStrRelease dead_acute
KeyStrPress a
KeyStrRelease a
```

But I can also use the "`String`" command inside the code, in order to write a more complex single-line sentence, which will result in an easy to read/understand portion of code, something like:

```
String Está lista la electrónica?
```

As you can see, words with accents are `Está` and `electrónica`. But when I try to play that portion of code, the accent letters won't appear, resulting in an incomplete sentence like this:

```
Est lista la electrnica?
```

I have read that I need to use unicode in order to reproduce such accent words, but even when I already know the corresponding unicode symbols, I don't know how to implement on this.

I would appreciate a lot if anyone explains how to solve this and/or provide any alternatives which play fair with accented words.

Words with accents, special letters like ñ, Ñ and the majority of the special symbols like @ ½ ~ ¬ ° and some other won't work so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: X-macro hasn't updated since 2000, and since then the author had _Better keyboard (keycode/keysym) and character translation_ in his ToDo... You can check other option like Autokey https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk , it can insert text and much more via python scripting, and fire those actions via key combos or abbreviations.